# Error: Component Class instance initialization error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error-messages

I've had multiple components pop up with this error. The function is always W.protoype.Bb and seems to be in the internal salesforce code. Sometimes the descriptor (i.e. markup://lightning:layout) will be different but the error is the same otherwise. Another thing is that the error isn't consistent. I personally have rarely encountered the issue but other users have reported seeing the error multiple times. The only solution that I've found so far is for the user to clear their cache and open salesforce again but this is a large interruption of daily work. Any ideas?

[image: error]

EDIT:

Here's the section that's referenced in the error message.

```
queryOpportunity: function (component, id){
    var action = component.get('c.fetchOpportunity');
    action.setParams({ "selectedId" : id });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a){
        var result = a.getReturnValue();
        component.set('v.opportunity', result.opp);
        component.set('v.fieldsGrid', result.fields);
        component.set('v.promisePermission', result.promisePermission);
        component.set('v.contacts', result.contacts);

        if(result.products == null || result.products.length <= 0){
            component.set('v.products', null);
        }
        else{
            component.set('v.products', result.products);
        }

        var child = component.find('opportunitydata');
        child.loadGrid();
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

EDIT 2:

Here's the apex code for fetchOpportunity

```
public static OpportunityWrapper getOpp(String selectedId){
    OpportunityWrapper wrapper = new OpportunityWrapper();
    Opportunity o = [SELECT RecordType.Name, RecordTypeId, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=: selectedId];
    String rec = o.RecordType.Name;
    String accountId = o.AccountId;
    List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>();
    String query = 'SELECT Id, RecordType.Name, ';
    if(rec == 'Executive Suites'){
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fields = SObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.ExecutiveSuites.getFields();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fields){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
            fieldNames.add(String.valueOf(f.getFieldPath()));
        }
        query = query.removeEndIgnoreCase(', ');            

    }
    else if(rec == 'Ticket Sales'){
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fields = SObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.TicketSales.getFields();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fields){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ',';
            fieldNames.add(String.valueOf(f.getFieldPath()));
        }
        query = query.removeEndIgnoreCase(','); 
    }
    else if(rec == 'Ticket Renewal - Full Season'){
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fields = SObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.TicketRenewal.getFields();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fields){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ',';
            fieldNames.add(String.valueOf(f.getFieldPath()));
        }
        query = query.removeEndIgnoreCase(','); 
    }
    else if(rec == 'Arena Group Sales'){
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fields = SObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.ArenaGroupSales.getFields();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fields){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ',';
            fieldNames.add(String.valueOf(f.getFieldPath()));
        }
        query = query.removeEndIgnoreCase(','); 
    }
    else if(rec == 'Ticket Renewal - Partial Season'){
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fields = SObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.TicketRenewalPartial.getFields();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fields){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ',';
            fieldNames.add(String.valueOf(f.getFieldPath()));
        }
        query = query.removeEndIgnoreCase(','); 
    }
    else{
        System.debug('Unknown record type.');
    }
    if(!query.contains('OwnerId')){
        query += ',OwnerId ';
    }
    query += ' FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = \'' + selectedId + '\'';
    System.debug('DEBUG --> query: ' + query);
    o = database.query(query);
    wrapper.opp = o;
    wrapper.fields = fieldNames;

    List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = [SELECT Product2.Name, Product2Id, Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice, Net_Revenue__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =: o.Id];
    wrapper.products = lineItems;
    System.debug('PRODUCTS: ' + lineItems);

    wrapper.contacts = getContacts(accountId);

    Profile prof = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
    PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Name, ID FROM PermissionSet Where Name='Promise_Task_Creation'];
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> psa = [SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId=: UserInfo.getUserId()];
    Boolean yes = false;
    for(PermissionSetAssignment p : psa){
        if(p.PermissionSetId == ps.Id){
            yes = true;
        }
    }
    if(yes || UserInfo.getProfileId() == prof.Id){
        System.debug('User can see!');
        wrapper.promisePermission = true;
    }
    else{
        System.debug('User cannot see.');
        wrapper.promisePermission = false;
    }
    return wrapper;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static OpportunityWrapper fetchOpportunity(String selectedId){
    return getOpp(selectedId);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet? Lightning Obfuscate the actual error message so its hard to debug. I can see from the error that custom lightning component is used, thus this can be due to developers code error.

Comment: I added the code. I've been using salesforce CLI to help find any syntax errors so hopefully that isn't the issue going on here.

Comment: What do you have in the stack trace? Also are you able to see the console logs to see if there's any server error?

Comment: Since I've only gotten this issue once and other users are the ones reporting, I haven't been able to see the console logs for each case. When I last got it, everything appeared fine and I didn't get any errors in the console. The problem is that this error only shows up every once in a while for some users while other users will never get it.

Comment: the method that failed was fetchOpportunity, which doesnt seem to be here in the code snippet you posted

Comment: Added the apex code. I've never had any errors from the apex side of things, at least from what I've seen through my test code and checking the logs in developer console.

Comment: Based on a similar (and if not same) experience, it turned out to be an access issue on one of the fields that was being queried in the apex method, where the logged in user did not have access to. You may like to verify it from that front.